# Java 8 conditional .map() (or map with identity function)

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, option-type

Suppose we have boolean flag to turn on/off map in a stream. For example to trim or not.

Are the below examples proper solution or there is a better way to implement that?

```
boolean doTrim = true;
optionalValue.map(doTrim ? String::trim : (x) -> x ).get()...
```

or:

```
boolean doTrim = true;
optionalValue.map(doTrim ? String::trim : Function.identity() ).get()...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-complicating things. If you have an `Optional<String> optionalValue` you can simply say:

```
if(doTrim) optionalValue=optionalValue.map(String::trim);
```

and proceed afterwards, e.g. call `get` on it.

But if you are calling `get()` unconditionally as in your example, you have to be confident, that the `Optional` isn’t, well, *optional*, but present. If you *know* that the `String` is present, you can do it even simpler:

```
String s=optionalValue.get();
if(doTrim) s=s.trim();
```

If you insist on having all the code inline, you can, of course, write it like:

```
(doTrim? optionalValue: optionalValue.map(String::trim)).get()
```

or

```
(doTrim? optionalValue.get(): optionalValue.get().trim())
```

But there is no real advantage over an ordinary `if` statement here. If you have a real *optional* value, not knowing whether the `String` is present, and don’t want to call `get` immediately, I’d recommend the first version of my answer as it allows to proceed with the `Optional` in any way you like. Your variant of selecting between `String::trim` and an identity function may look more funky but has no real advantage over conventional programming.

Comment: The advantage of everything "inline" is avoiding mutable local variables, which are a common cause of hard-to-trace bugs when combined with large blocks of code. A mutable local unleashes the potential of changing it at any line of code, imposing an increased cognitive load on the programmer. On the other hand, small code blocks should be preferred anyway, in which case the difference diminishes.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: It’s hard to tell, whether `doTrim` is mutable, but at least it seems to originate from a distant code location, so the suspicious design is already there, while in my second example, the mutable local variable only exists because I don’t know what follow-up action to perform with the `String` as the question’s code is to narrow. In my code, such an action would never appear as either the source would be capable to provide the `String` trimmed if demanded or the follow-up action would be able to find the right boundaries for the `String` processing when needed.

Comment: In your first example, `optionalValue` is forced to be mutable; in the second case it is the `s` variable. OP's code involves no mutable locals in the idiom under discussion; `doTrim` is just an outside parameter and could very well be immutable, possibly replaced with a method invocation in real code. Also I would consider the role of `trim` in the question as just a simple example to motivate the idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Two perspectives:

1. From Java language perspective

   Both are same.
2. From JVM byte code instruction perspective

   They are different. `(x) -> x` is translated to **InvokeDynamic**, while `Function.identity()` is translated to traditional **InterfaceMethod**.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is not really functional and the boolean flag is a code smell that hints at the problem: instead of

```
if flag then map(foo) else map(bar)
```

you better pass the function that will get mapped over the optional and say

```
map(f)
```

The benefit is clear: As it stands, your code can either trim the string or do nothing. But next week, you'll want it also uppercased, or lowercased, or trimmed, reversed and uppercased in certain instances. What do you do then? Write an enum?