# Is there a Java 8 .or() which returns Optional of present value or default provided?

Tags: java, null, functional-programming, java-8, option-type

Suppose I want to provide default value if input value is null, but want to still process `Optional` type, not target type, like this:

`Optional.of(testedValue == null ? testedValue : "" ).map(String::trim)...`

Note that I can't use `.or` because it not returns optional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest another Optional:

```
Optional.of(
  Optional.ofNullable(input).orElse("")
).map(String::trim);
```

which is equivalent to

```
Optional.of(
  Optional.ofNullable(input).orElse("").trim()
);
```

So the benefit would be if you continue with more processing steps which may themselves result in no value.

Comment: I would prefer `Optional.of(Optional.ofNullable(input).map(String::trim).orElse(""))` as there is no sense in calling `trim` on an empty `String`. And perhaps the entire wrapping into another `Optional` becomes obsolete once that is understood…

Comment: Calling `trim()` on an empty string is extremely cheap and there's a good chance that the `map(String::trim)` approach is actually more expensive. For other cases it may be different.

Comment: Just to throw another option (heh) onto the pile:   `Optional.ofNullable(input).map(Optional::of).orElse(Optional.of(""))`

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: In your first solution, you are calling `map(String::trim)` anyway; I just changed the order of the statements to achieve the effect of not calling `trim` on an empty `String`. If you want to consider performance consequently, `input==null? "": input.trim()` might be the best option. However, what I questioned was the OP’s desire to wrap the result into another `Optional` which might be obsolete once it has been understood that calling `map` on the primary `Optional` is possible as well. Compare with [his other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27315959/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger I thought your statement was that you prefer your idiom to both of mine, and I don't involve a `map` step in the latter, nor do I see the need for it in this case. --- OP's desire is to have a default string inserted early into the pipeline, then entering further steps which work with that. Those steps are not shown in the question, but are implied. I don't see OP wanting a nested Optional, that was only my proposal.

Comment: The OP says “I want to provide default value if input value is null, but want to still process `Optional` type”; either you accept his requirement (then your second example fails as it doesn’t process it as requested) or you agree with me that it is nonsensical to use `Optional` after injecting the default value, as you know that it is non-`null` and you call methods directly (as you did in your second example). “Early into the pipeline” makes no sense for `Optional`s as there is no pipeline, unlike `Stream`s they are not lazy but performing the action immediately.

Comment: @Holger OP's own code doesn't have the nested Optional, for one. He wants to rewrite that code to better use the Optional API, whether it be a nested Optional or something else. My second example results in an Optional ready to accept further processing steps, already initialized with an arbitrary default value substituting for null input, therefore meeting OP's requirement in full. --- As for my usage of the term "pipeline", it is not reserved for the strict and narrow meaning it has in the Streams API. Here I'm using it in a slightly different meaning.

Comment: But `.map(String::trim)` *is* already an example of “further processing steps”. If you turn that into an ordinary method invocation and just wrap the result into an `Optional`, you can do that with *every* other follow-up step as well which brings us back to the starting point, the final wrapping into an `Optional` is obsolete.

Comment: @Holger And what about further `filter` or `flatMap` steps? What is your proposed idiom in that case (because that's what I see as the true motivation for this question, having similar examples in my code)? Also, take into account that the substitute for `trim` may also return `null`.